# How to set console color with .net core in OSX

Tags: macos, .net-core

I'm playing around with .NET core 1.0 on OSX 10.11.5 (El Capitan).  Simply changing Console.ForegroundColor seems to have no impact on the console text color from the command line.

```
     Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
     Console.WriteLine("Yellow");
```

I tried updating my bash config

```
export CLICOLOR=1
```

Is there anything else I should be doing?

Comment: Did you restart your terminal after updating the config? Your code produces yellow output for me.

Comment: First I just did a "source ~/.bash_profile" but then I restarted the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out.  It is a difference between .NET core 1.0 versions.  I didn't realize the suffix until running

```
dotnet --version
```

Previously I had:

```
1.0.0-preview1-002702
```

After re-downloading and installing the SDX, I now have:

```
1.0.0-preview2-003121
```

This must have been a bug that the team corrected.

Thanks all.